# When you name an element in an uncountably categorical theory....

Tags: model-theory

When you name an element in an uncountably categorical theory $T$ does it remains uncountably categorical?

In other words, given a finite elementary map $f:M\to N$ between models of an uncountably categorical theory $T$ of equal uncountable cardinality, is there an isomorphism $h:M\to N$ that extends $f$?

(The language is countable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to see the answer: The Baldwin-Lachlan theorem says that a theory $T$ in a countable language is uncountably categorical if and only if it is $\omega$-stable and has no Vaughtian pairs, and both of these conditions are clearly preserved under naming countably many constants.

Of course, tomasz's method is better, since it shows that you can name $\kappa$ many constants, and the resulting theory will still be $\lambda$-categorical for all $\lambda > \kappa$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question the answer is yes. Notice that a categorical structure is automatically saturated and use a standard back-and-forth argument.

For the second question the answer is no, not even if $M,N$ are isomorphic. Just consider the theory of one equivalence relation with two infinite classes.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. In fact you can name as many constant as you want (in contrast with ω-categorical theories). But there is no second question: they are exactly the same. The theory of one equivalence relation is ω-categorical but not uncountably categorical. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: @PrimoPetri: The second question is your "in other words", which is really quite different. The theory I mentioned has two models of cardinality $\aleph_1$ with an elementary map between them which does not extend to an isomorphism. Also, you can only name a set of constants smaller than the entire model. Otherwise, there may be no space left for a back-and-forth.

Comment: @tomasz But the question was about uncountably categorical theories, and the theory of one equivalence relation with two infinite classes is not uncountably categorical.... Primo is correct that the questions are equivalent.

Comment: I edited the second wording of the question in the hope to avoid misunderstandings.  You can name as many elements as you want then do the back and forth between sufficiently large models (by Morley theorem).

Comment: Also, I don't think that the fact that every uncountable model of an uncountably categorical theory is saturated is something that you can just "notice". You can get this fact from the proof of Morley's theorem, but it doesn't even follow immediately from the statement of Morley's theorem.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: The initial statement of the question was ambiguous there, like the second paragraph was a rewording of the whole question, which it wasn't. About the second comment, I guess you're right, it is not as trivial as I had thought.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: On the other hand, I think it follows by a pretty simple elementary chain argument once you establish $\omega$-stability (or more precisely, stability in cardinality $<\kappa$).